# Weird OpenGL Texture Display

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am drawing a 3D cube with texture and i get sth like this. I dont exactly know what is wrong ;/
https://i.stack.imgur.com/081nl.png

Vectors for texturecord

```
    vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
    vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
    vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
    vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),

....
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 9));
....
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "mySampler"), 0);
....
color = texture(myTextureSampler,UV); //SHADER CODE
```

To load first example i used:

```
SDL_Surface* textures;
textures = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, textures->w, textures->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textures->pixels);
```

To second pics i used :

```
int width, height;
    GLubyte * data;
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL) return 0;
    width = 128;
    height = 128;
    data = (GLubyte *)malloc(width * height * 3);
    //int size = fseek(file,);
    fread(data, width * height * 3, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    {
        int index = i * 3;
        unsigned char B, R;
        B = data[index];
        R = data[index + 2];

        data[index] = R;
        data[index + 2] = B;
    }
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 128, 128, 0, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

The both doesnt work correct;// any ideas?

Complete program:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <GL\glew.h> // UP
#include <GL\glut.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm\gtx\transform.hpp>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace glm;

GLuint LoadTexture(const char * filename)
{
    int width, height;
    GLubyte * data;
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL) return 0;
    width = 128;
    height = 128;
    data = (GLubyte *)malloc(width * height * 3);
    //int size = fseek(file,);
    fread(data, width * height * 3, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    {
        int index = i * 3;
        unsigned char B, R;
        B = data[index];
        R = data[index + 2];

        data[index] = R;
        data[index + 2] = B;
    }

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    //free(data);

    return texture;
    /**
    SDL_Surface* textures;
    textures = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, textures->w, textures->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textures->pixels);
    return texture;
    **/
}
std::string LoadFileToString(const char* filepath){
    std::string fileData = "";
    std::ifstream stream(filepath, std::ios::in);

    if (stream.is_open()){
        std::string line = "";
        while (getline(stream, line)){
            fileData += "\n" + line;
        }
        stream.close();
    }
    return fileData;
}
GLuint LoadShaders(const char*VertShaderPath, const char* fragShaderPath){
    GLuint vertShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    std::string vertShaderSource = LoadFileToString(VertShaderPath);
    std::string fragShaderSource = LoadFileToString(fragShaderPath);

    const char*  rawVertShaderSource = vertShaderSource.c_str();
    const char*  rawfragShaderSource = fragShaderSource.c_str();

    glShaderSource(vertShader, 1, &rawVertShaderSource, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fragShader, 1, &rawfragShaderSource, NULL);

    glCompileShader(vertShader);
    glCompileShader(fragShader);

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragShader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    return program;
}

const float movementspeed = 0.01f;
class Camera{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 viewDirection;
    const vec3 UP;
    vec2 oldmouseposition;
public:
    Camera();
    mat4 getWorldToViewMatrix() const;
    void mouseUpdate(const vec2 &newMousePosition);
    void moveForward();
    void moveBackWard();
    void left();
    void right();
    void up();
    void down();

};
Camera::Camera() :viewDirection(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), UP(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f){}
void Camera::mouseUpdate(const vec2 &newMousePosition){

    glm::vec2 mouseDelta = newMousePosition - oldmouseposition;
    if (glm::length(mouseDelta) >10.0f)
    {
        oldmouseposition = newMousePosition;
        return;
    }
    viewDirection = glm::mat3(glm::rotate(-mouseDelta.x*0.5f, UP)) * viewDirection;
    oldmouseposition = newMousePosition;

}
void Camera::moveForward(){
    position -= movementspeed *viewDirection;
}
void Camera::moveBackWard(){
    position += movementspeed *viewDirection;
}
void Camera::left(){
    glm::vec3 strafeDirection = glm::cross(viewDirection, UP);
    position += movementspeed *strafeDirection;
}
void Camera::right(){
    glm::vec3 strafeDirection = glm::cross(viewDirection, UP);
    position += -movementspeed *strafeDirection;
}
void Camera::up(){
    position += movementspeed *UP;
}
void Camera::down(){
    position += -movementspeed *UP;
}
mat4 Camera::getWorldToViewMatrix() const {
    return lookAt(position, position - viewDirection, UP);
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My 3D World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    GLuint program = LoadShaders("vertex.wss", "fragment.fss"); // shadersprogram

    struct Vertex{
        glm::vec3 position;
        glm::vec3 color;
        glm::vec2 texture;
        glm::vec3 normal;
    };
    Vertex verts[] = {
        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 0
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 1
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 2
        vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 3
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal

        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 4
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 5
        vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 7
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), //normal

        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 8
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 9
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 10
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 11
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), //normal

        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 12
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 13
        vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 14
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 15
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal

        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 16
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 17
        vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 18
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 19
        vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal

        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 20
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 21
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 22
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 23
        vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) //normal
    };
    GLushort indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, // Top
        4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, // Front
        8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, // Right
        12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, // Left
        16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, // Back
        20, 22, 21, 20, 23, 22 // Bottom
    };
    ////////VAO niepotrzebne
    ////////VBO
    GLuint vboID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    GLuint indexbuff;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexbuff);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexbuff);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    //////


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, LoadTexture("block"));

    Camera camera;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



        glUseProgram(program);

        double xpos, ypos;
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);

        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.moveForward();
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.moveBackWard();
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.left();
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.right();
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_R) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.up();
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_F) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.down();
        }
        if (xpos > 0 && xpos < 640 && ypos>0 && ypos < 400){
            camera.mouseUpdate(vec2(float(xpos / 50), float(ypos / 50)));
            std::cout << "pos x: " << xpos << "pos y: " << ypos << std::endl;
        }

        // textures
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "mySampler"), 0);
        //AMBIENT LIGHT
        GLint ambientlightlocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "ambientLight");
        vec3 ambientLight(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
        glUniform3fv(ambientlightlocation, 1, &ambientLight[0]);

        //Light
        GLint lightlocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "lightPosition");
        vec3 lightposition(1.0f, 1.0f, -3.75f);
        glUniform3fv(lightlocation, 1, &lightposition[0]);


        GLint fullTransformMatrixUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "fullTransformMatrix");
        mat4 fullTransformMatrix;
        mat4 projectionMatrix = perspective(90.0f, (480.0f / 640.0f), 0.1f, 5.0f);
        mat4 worldToProjectionMatrix = projectionMatrix* camera.getWorldToViewMatrix();

        //CUBE 1 tak sie robi gdyby sie roznily
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (void*)0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 6));
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 9));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexbuff);

        mat4 cube1WorldMatrix = translate(vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, -3.75f)) * rotate(0.0f, vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
        fullTransformMatrix = worldToProjectionMatrix *cube1WorldMatrix;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(fullTransformMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &fullTransformMatrix[0][0]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        // CUBE 2 gdyby byly rozne 
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (void*)0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 6));
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 9));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexbuff);

        mat4 cube2WorldMatrix = translate(vec3(-3.0f, 0.0f, -3.75f)) * rotate(126.0f, vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        fullTransformMatrix = worldToProjectionMatrix *cube2WorldMatrix;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(fullTransformMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &fullTransformMatrix[0][0]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

fragment.fss:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;

in vec3 theColor;
in vec2 UV;

uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;

void main()
{
    color = texture(myTextureSampler,UV);
    //texture(myTextureSampler,UV);
    // * vec4(theColor,1.0);

}
```

vertex.wss:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location=0) in vec3 in_pos;
layout(location=1) in vec3 vertexColor;
layout(location=2) in vec2 vertexUV;
layout(location=3) in vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 fullTransformMatrix;


uniform vec3 ambientLight;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

out vec3 theColor;
out vec2 UV;

void main()
{
    vec4 v = vec4(in_pos, 1.0);
    gl_Position = fullTransformMatrix* v;

    vec3 lightVector = normalize(lightPosition-normal);
    float brightness = dot(lightVector,normal);
    theColor = vertexColor * vec3( brightness, brightness, brightness);// * ambientLight;

    UV = vertexUV;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_layout) snafu with RGB.  Do you ever set it to  `1` (from the default `4`) before the `glTexImage2D()` call(s)?

Comment: glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); doesn't help

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then.

Comment: https://github.com/dex36/OpenGL

Comment: [Working fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TADdR.png) on [my end](http://pastebin.com/7XBgUgb1) with a hard-coded texture.  Is the `block` file truly a tightly-packed sequence of RGB triplets as implied by your parsing code in `LoadTexture()`?  I.e., you didn't just rename a PNG/JPG/BMP? (which I've seen people do :))

Comment: yup i see it's working so there is a some problem with loading data from pics to array ;p could you give me some example of working PNG?

Comment: A PNG *decoder*?  You'll want something like [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) or [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) or [`libpng`](http://libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If [you](https://web.archive.org/web/20151109231550/http://stackoverflow.com/users/5410670/dex3) want to load compressed images you'll need a proper decoder.

Your `LoadTexture()` function was assuming everything passed in
is an uncompressed, tightly-packed blob of RGB triplets, which is...not a good assumption :)

Here's an example using [`stb_image`](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) and a [screenshot PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TADdR.png):

```
GLuint LoadTexture(const char * filename)
{
    int width = 0, height = 0, n = 0;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load
        (
        filename,
        &width,
        &height,
        &n,
        3
        );

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    stbi_image_free( data );

    return texture;
}
```

[image: yo dawg!]

All together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include <glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm\gtx\transform.hpp>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

using namespace glm;

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* shader, ... )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, shader );
        while( shader )
        {
            const GLenum type = va_arg( args, GLenum );
            AttachShader( prog, type, shader );
            shader = va_arg( args, const char* );
        }
        va_end( args );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const char* vert = GLSL
(
    330 core,
    layout(location=0) in vec3 in_pos;
    layout(location=1) in vec3 vertexColor;
    layout(location=2) in vec2 vertexUV;
    layout(location=3) in vec3 normal;

    uniform mat4 fullTransformMatrix;

    uniform vec3 ambientLight;
    uniform vec3 lightPosition;

    out vec3 theColor;
    out vec2 UV;

    void main()
    {
        vec4 v = vec4(in_pos, 1.0);
        gl_Position = fullTransformMatrix* v;

        vec3 lightVector = normalize(lightPosition-normal);
        float brightness = dot(lightVector,normal);
        theColor = vertexColor * vec3( brightness, brightness, brightness);// * ambientLight;

        UV = vertexUV;
    }
);

const char* frag = GLSL
(
    330 core,
    out vec4 color;

    in vec3 theColor;
    in vec2 UV;

    uniform sampler2D mySampler;

    void main()
    {
        color = texture(mySampler,UV);
    }
);


GLuint LoadTexture(const char * filename)
{
    int width = 0, height = 0, n = 0;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load
        (
        filename,
        &width,
        &height,
        &n,
        3
        );

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    stbi_image_free( data );

    return texture;
}

const float movementspeed = 0.01f;
class Camera{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 viewDirection;
    const vec3 UP;
    vec2 oldmouseposition;
public:
    Camera();
    mat4 getWorldToViewMatrix() const;
    void mouseUpdate(const vec2 &newMousePosition);
    void moveForward();
    void moveBackWard();
    void left();
    void right();
    void up();
    void down();

};
Camera::Camera() :viewDirection(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), UP(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f){}
void Camera::mouseUpdate(const vec2 &newMousePosition){

    glm::vec2 mouseDelta = newMousePosition - oldmouseposition;
    if (glm::length(mouseDelta) >10.0f)
    {
        oldmouseposition = newMousePosition;
        return;
    }
    viewDirection = glm::mat3(glm::rotate(-mouseDelta.x*0.5f, UP)) * viewDirection;
    oldmouseposition = newMousePosition;

}
void Camera::moveForward(){
    position -= movementspeed *viewDirection;
}
void Camera::moveBackWard(){
    position += movementspeed *viewDirection;
}
void Camera::left(){
    glm::vec3 strafeDirection = glm::cross(viewDirection, UP);
    position += movementspeed *strafeDirection;
}
void Camera::right(){
    glm::vec3 strafeDirection = glm::cross(viewDirection, UP);
    position += -movementspeed *strafeDirection;
}
void Camera::up(){
    position += movementspeed *UP;
}
void Camera::down(){
    position += -movementspeed *UP;
}
mat4 Camera::getWorldToViewMatrix() const {
    return lookAt(position, position - viewDirection, UP);
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My 3D World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    GLuint program = Program::Load
        (
        vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
        frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
        NULL
        );

    struct Vertex{
        glm::vec3 position;
        glm::vec3 color;
        glm::vec2 texture;
        glm::vec3 normal;
    };
    Vertex verts[] = {
        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 0
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 1
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 2
        vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 3
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal

        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 4
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 5
        vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 7
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), //normal

        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 8
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 9
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 10
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 11
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), //normal

        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 12
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), // 13
        vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 14
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 15
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal

        vec3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 16
        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), // 17
        vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 18
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 19
        vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal

        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 20
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), // 21
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 0.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 22
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // Colour
        vec2(1.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //normal
        vec3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), // 23
        vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), // Colour
        vec2(0.0f, 1.0f),
        vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) //normal
    };
    GLushort indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, // Top
        4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, // Front
        8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, // Right
        12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, // Left
        16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, // Back
        20, 22, 21, 20, 23, 22 // Bottom
    };
    ////////VAO niepotrzebne
    ////////VBO
    GLuint vboID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    GLuint indexbuff;
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexbuff);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexbuff);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    //////

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, LoadTexture("TADdR.png"));

    Camera camera;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
        glUseProgram(program);

        double xpos, ypos;
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
    
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.moveForward();
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.moveBackWard();
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.left();
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.right();
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_R) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.up();
        }
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_F) == GLFW_PRESS){
            camera.down();
        }
        if (xpos > 0 && xpos < 640 && ypos>0 && ypos < 400){
            camera.mouseUpdate(vec2(float(xpos / 50), float(ypos / 50)));
            std::cout << "pos x: " << xpos << "pos y: " << ypos << std::endl;
        }

        // textures
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "mySampler"), 0);
        //AMBIENT LIGHT
        GLint ambientlightlocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "ambientLight");
        vec3 ambientLight(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
        glUniform3fv(ambientlightlocation, 1, &ambientLight[0]);

        //Light
        GLint lightlocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "lightPosition");
        vec3 lightposition(1.0f, 1.0f, -3.75f);
        glUniform3fv(lightlocation, 1, &lightposition[0]);


        GLint fullTransformMatrixUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "fullTransformMatrix");
        mat4 fullTransformMatrix;
        mat4 projectionMatrix = perspective( glm::radians( 90.0f ), (480.0f / 640.0f), 0.1f, 5.0f);
        mat4 worldToProjectionMatrix = projectionMatrix* camera.getWorldToViewMatrix();

        //CUBE 1 tak sie robi gdyby sie roznily
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (void*)0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 6));
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 9));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexbuff);

        mat4 cube1WorldMatrix = translate(vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, -3.75f)) * rotate(0.0f, vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
        fullTransformMatrix = worldToProjectionMatrix *cube1WorldMatrix;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(fullTransformMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &fullTransformMatrix[0][0]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    
        // CUBE 2 gdyby byly rozne 
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (void*)0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 3));
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 6));
        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 11, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 9));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexbuff);

        mat4 cube2WorldMatrix = translate(vec3(-3.0f, 0.0f, -3.75f)) * rotate(126.0f, vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        fullTransformMatrix = worldToProjectionMatrix *cube2WorldMatrix;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(fullTransformMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &fullTransformMatrix[0][0]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```